# Installed gem 'typus' not found in bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

Okay. So, I'm nearly at my wits' end. :/

I've installed the Typus 3.0.10 gem with 'gem install typus' (on Windows 7 w/ Rails 3).
I cd into my Rails app and 'bundle install'. When I search for the gem (bundle show typus), it can't be found. Running 'rails generate typus' cannot find the generator. Looking in my Gemfile (Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems), I clearly see the Typus folder with everything in it.

The same thing also happened for the 'admin_data' gem, so I know I'm doing something wrong.
It seems as though any new gem I install isn't put into the bundle.

Please help! If I'm leaving out any info, let me know.

Comment: Okay, got it pretty quickly. Stupid really, but once I installed the actual gem, I didn't realize I needed to open my Gemfile in the application and add 

    gem 'typus'

so that the 'bundle install' would recognize it.

Answer (score 1):

You have installed it on your local machine, but you need to add the gem to your Gemfile as well. Then doing a bundle install should locate it on your machine and use it.

Comment: This is correct. Without it being in the `Gemfile`, it won't be in the `Gemfile.lock` file either and so Bundler will not load it.